# Which of the two links to follow for adding ads using admob?

Tags: android, admob

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob

or

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US

Both links follow different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide [Offical Guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en_US) this very well explained

Answer (score 0):

The Google way is updated and better but I personally saw [this video first, as a reference,](http://youtu.be/8IerupLaakE) and then read the Google instructions. It will clear all your doubts.

It has 3 videos and they all are elaborated.